Minimize function in PyTorch using dummy variables
I am new to PyTorch so my question could be trivial.
I am trying to minimize a function which I could resume in a snippet as

def target_function(params):
    vector = torch.zeros(10)
    μr = torch.zeros(2, requires_grad=True)
   
    θ = torch.zeros(2, requires_grad=True)

    μr = torch.tensor([params[0], params[4]], requires_grad=True)

    θ = torch.tensor([params[3], params[7]], requires_grad=True)
 
    for i in range(2):
        vector[i] += (μr[i]**2 - θ[i] ).sum()

    return torch.norm(vector)

I tried performing the optimization via
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Initialize parameters with random values between 0 and 1
params = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True)


# Choose an optimizer (e.g., SGD) and specify the learning rate
optimizer = SGD([params], lr=0.01)

num_steps = 100

# Lists to store the values of the target function during optimization
target_values = []

# Optimization loop
for i in range(num_steps):
    # Zero gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    # Compute the function value
    output = target_function(params)
    
    # Store the function value
    target_values.append(output.item())
    
    # Compute gradients
    output.backward()
    
    # Update parameters
    optimizer.step()

# Plot the values of the target function during optimization
plt.plot(target_values)
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Target Function Value')
plt.title('Optimization Progress')
plt.show()


but it seems that the values of the function do not evolve during the loop.
Debugging I found out that it may depend on using the variables μr and θ in the code. Probably I am doing something which should not be done but I do not understand how to fix this keeping the variables μr and θ.
Thanks for any help or explanation

Can you clarify what you are trying to do here? For example why are you defining μr and θ twice? Why are params and vector of size 10 when you only use specific elements from them?

@Karl Yes of course. Actually the target_function is more complicated than this one. So I left the original paramsof size 10. I am defining  μr and θjust for clarity when writing the formulas which define the vector which should be minimized. I only reported this little script since I found out that indeed the error comes from the use of θand μr. If you use params[i] the error does not occours

the problem with you is the μr = torch.tensor([params[0], params[4]], requires_grad=True) and θ = torch.tensor([params[3], params[7]], requires_grad=True). You create new tensors, and their reference is difference than the params, so the params is not updated in the traning loops. You can change them to
    μr = torch.stack([params[0], params[4]])
    θ = torch.stack([params[3], params[7]])

then you can train as normal
